# Proper HostName Verifier in app according to Googe Play Store

Tags: android, https, android-security, sslhandshakeexception

I am using following code till now to call "https" APIs in app.

```
 public class HttpsTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

private static TrustManager[] trustManagers;
private static final X509Certificate[] _AcceptedIssuers = new X509Certificate[]{};

@SuppressLint("TrustAllX509TrustManager")
@Override
public void checkClientTrusted(
        X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s)
        throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {

}

@SuppressLint("TrustAllX509TrustManager")
@Override
public void checkServerTrusted(
        X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s)
        throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {

}

public boolean isClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain) {
    return true;
}

public boolean isServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
    return _AcceptedIssuers;
}

public static void allowAllSSL() {
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {

        @Override
        public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
            return true;
        }

    });

    SSLContext context = null;
    if (trustManagers == null) {
        trustManagers = new TrustManager[]{new HttpsTrustManager()};
    }

    try {
        context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
}

}
```

I am new to android security changes done by google play store.I am getting this warning from Play Store:

**change the verify method in your custom HostnameVerifier interface to return false whenever the hostname of the server does not meet your expectations.**

I want to know that what kind of changes i should do in app or server?? I have tried other links present in stack Overflow but I am not geeting clarity of this that should i modify app or just create signed certificate in server?

Solution that i can find but not sure it will work or not

If I add following code :

```
 `HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession arg1) {
            if (hostname.equalsIgnoreCase("https://xxxxxx.xx") ){

                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }});`
```

then will it not make any issue in play store?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Security Alert From Google For Android APP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42087342/security-alert-from-google-for-android-app)

Comment: No.. I am not getting clarity from this link..I have edited my question.Please check.I am not sure about solution that i am trying.Please have a look

Comment: if you follow the link, then yes, provided all the hostnames your app uses. Don't forget to test and debug the app (put a breakpoint inside the `verify()` method) to confirm that your app will run properly after whitelisting the hostnames.

Comment: My concern is that alert given by play store is just because i have not  given my domain name under if else condition inside verify().If i provide this as mentioned in edited post then play store will not show error or there is something else that should be done like adding certificate etc.?

Comment: That is not a valid or secure implementation of SSL.  You should delete all of this code.  The only thing your `allowAllSSL` does is completely disable all SSL security.  You're opening your users up to network-based eavesdropping and attacks by doing this.

Answer (score 1):

That is not a valid or secure implementation of SSL, nor is your proposed solution.

The correct solution is to delete all of this code.

The only thing your `allowAllSSL` method does is completely disable all SSL security. You're opening your users up to network-based eavesdropping and attacks by doing this.

Comment: then if i do not use this code, API call giving SSL handshake exception..then where to check for solution? app side or server side?