# Is it possible to upload an app to Google Play without using HostnameVerifier?

Tags: java, ssl, google-play

If I only call startHandshake() to establish an SSL connection without verifying the host name, will uploading to Google Play fail? Just like the code below.

```
ssl = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket("8.8.8.8", 500);
ssl.startHandshake();
ssl.getOutputStream(). write("hello, world".getBytes());
```

I found that some people were warned by Google that they did not use HostnameVerifier correctly, which caused the application upload to fail.

like this: [Proper HostName Verifier in app according to Googe Play Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61630194/proper-hostname-verifier-in-app-according-to-googe-play-store)

Comment: That question is about replacing the SSL policy. You're not modifying that, just using the default.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am new at android development. Do you mean that the above code is allowed to be uploaded to Google play store? Even if it does not verify the host name.

Comment: It _should_ be, but you really ought to be using a higher-level library (such as Retrofit) to handle this stuff for you.